# $destroy in directive on component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a component and an attribute directive on it, like this:
`<my-component my-directive>`.

When component is destroyed I call `$scope.$destroy();` ($scope is injected in component controller).

Inside directive's `link` function I have a listener like this:
`$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {...` and the problem is that it's not working. It seems that those are different scopes.

Now I have a workaround:

Add `$ctrl.scope = $scope;` in component controller

`require : '^myComponent',` and use `myComponent.scope` - then it works.

The question is: how can I listen for component destroy inside directive?

*addition*: This `myComponent` is created using `$compile` in case it changes something

Answer (score 1):

You can access the controller from your directive by using `$ctrl` property of scope,
Then use `$onDestroy(...)` from your directive on the component controller instance, (instead of `$on('destroy',...)` in scope) to listen to destroy of a component scope.

Comment: Well, it's much the same as my workaround. But I wonder if there's some better, more native way

Comment: hmm, but the documentation for the component destroy says `Replace any $scope.$on('$destroy') instances in your Controller with $onDestroy() lifecycle hook`

Comment: Isnt it just a sugar?

Comment: @k102 How can it be more native than that? $onDestroy is the way it's supposed to be done in controllers. Everything's sugar. `component` is a sugar for `directive`. `directive` is a sugar for `factory`.